# I do not have an Ethernet port on my desktop PC

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Add An Ethernet?](https://superuser.com/questions/27256/how-to-add-an-ethernet)

I have an old desktop PC which is running on XP, I am on broadband currently using an external modem.  My ISP has sent me a Router, cables and Micro filter for me to set up a wireless connection.  I do not have an Ethernet port on my PC to plug in the RJ-45 cable.  Can I add an Ethernet port (like I did USB 2.0) and if so is it quite easy to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add a card in your computer. 
The best is to add the card IN the computer, this card should be great http://www.amazon.co.uk/D-Link-DFE-530TX-100Mbps-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B00004SYNX/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1321535586&sr=8-1

The installation is really simple, here you have a simple and really usefull guide for beginner ;) http://www.helpwithpcs.com/upgrading/install-pci-card.htm

Don't forget to tell us what happen and click on "resolved" !

Answer (score 0):

You could simply buy a random XP compatible network card. And it must meet the motherboard slots usually it should be a PCI card. If you are not sure which card to buy you might have to look into the manual of your motherboard. But it is quite simple as long as there are free slots.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: Buy a USB2.0-Ethernet-Adapter (be sure you have USB2.0, USB1.1 is too slow) or install a PCI (or even PCIe) ethernet adapter if there's a free slot in your desktop pc. They are cheap and will give the best results in terms of stability and throughput. intel-Desktop-Adapters will work fine with Windows XP. Look for GBit-Cards (1000Base-T) even though you may not need the speed, but they have other obligatory features like auto-sensing and auto-MDI-X that are nice to have.

The USB-Adapter is easier to install but a dedicated NIC will perform better.